# Set Javascript Prototype Dynamically

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

I am trying to set a prototype function dynamically using `new Function(...)`. I have tried the following (es6):

```
export default class AI {

    constructor(algObj, player) {
        this.player = player;
        this.algObj = algObj;

        //create the shoot and placeShips prototypes form the this.algObj property
        this.prototype.initialize   = new Function(this.algObj.initialize);
        this.prototype.shoot        = new Function(this.algObj.shoot);
        this.prototype.placeShips   = new Function(this.algObj.placeShips);

        this.initialize();
    }
}
```

USE CASE: I have a micro service that stores algorithms as the resource which will then be passed into a simulator that battles 2 algorithms.

when I try this, `this.prototype` is `undefined`. The only reason I can think this might be the case is because the `AI` object is not fully defined until after the constructor is done executing.

How would I go about setting a prototype function like I am trying to do here?

UPDATE:

```
this.__proto__.initialize   = new Function(this.algObj.initialize);
this.__proto__.shoot        = new Function(this.algObj.shoot);
this.__proto__.placeShips   = new Function(this.algObj.placeShips);
```

Comment: Are you planning to use AI for one object instance only?

Comment: I added a use case to my edit as well as an update.

Comment: There will by one AI instance per game and there will be multiple games per simulation.

Comment: You now have two questions: about prototype being undefined, and about assigned functions which are anonymous. Please don't mix these into one question: ask a separate one for each.

Comment: I will open another question for the anonymous function question

Comment: You [must not overwrite prototype methods from inside the constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28255957/1048572).

Comment: Note: if performance is critical, `new Function` isn't a good idea. If this bit isn't performance-intensive, you might be able to get away with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the constructor is invoked you already have an instance of the object you're creating, and thus you can simply modify the instance's methods without touching the prototype:

```
export default class AI {

    constructor(algObj, player) {
        this.player = player;
        this.algObj = algObj;

        //create the shoot and placeShips prototypes form the this.algObj property
        this.initialize   = new Function(this.algObj.initialize);
        this.shoot        = new Function(this.algObj.shoot);
        this.placeShips   = new Function(this.algObj.placeShips);

        this.initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works! So are the 3 functions then added to AI.prototype

Comment: @Frank No, they are added to the instance the constructor is, well, constructing. The prototype remains untouched.

Comment: @jfriend00: Apparently `algObj` contains code strings, otherwise it wouldn't work. Why it does that, and whether that is a good idea, we better discuss elsewhere.

Comment: Yea I use new Function because I'm passing in a string.