# JavaScript: instanceof operator unexpected result

Tags: javascript, prototype, instanceof

I've recently discovered prototypes for myself, and would be happy to get some help with figuring out the thing:

Code example 1:

```
    "use strict";

    var Car = function(loc) {
        var obj = Object.create(Car.prototype);
        obj.loc = loc;
        return obj;
    };

    Car.prototype.move = function() {
            this.loc++;
            return this.loc;
    };

    var bmw = Car(6);

    console.log( bmw instanceof Car );
```

Code example 2:

```
    "use strict";

    var Car = {
        "makeCar": function(loc) {
            var obj = Object.create(Car.prototype);
            obj.loc = loc;
            return obj;
        },
        "prototype": {
            "move": function() {
                this.loc++;
                return this.loc;
            }
        }
    };

    var bmw = Car.makeCar(6);

    console.log( bmw instanceof Car.makeCar );
```

I wrote example 2, cause I want to keep methods for Car object inside the object itself. I'm not sure if it can be done, but it's working so far, except the "instanceof" operator.

In the first example it will log "true", but in second it will log "false" and I've no idea where am I wrong, so counting on your help, thank you.

Comment: `Car.makeCar` is a _function_ not a _Car_ object.

Comment: `instanceof` tests whether the object's prototype chain contains the prototype of the constructor. `bmw`'s prototype chain contains `Car`, not `Car.makeCar`.

Comment: `bmw instanceof Car` does still work, because you're still creating the instance to inherit from  `Car.prototype`

Comment: My initial test for example 2 was console.log( bmw instanceof Car ); but in this case I've an error: "Uncaught TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not callable".

Comment: @Mike: Oh, right, `Car` would need to be a constructor for that to work. `Car.makeCar` is not a constructor and does not have the instances' prototype on its `.prototype` property, so that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Bergi so there is no way to have methods merged with constructor itself?

Comment: You can make it work by setting `Car.makeCar.prototype = Car.prototype`, but that's weird. Just keep the standard patterns. If you want to declare your methods in a structural unit together with the constructor, wrap everything in an IEFE [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28256166/1048572) or just use an ES6 `class`.

Comment: @Bergi oh, ok thank you, please combine this into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `console.log( bmw instanceof Car.makeCar );` yields `false`

…because `Car.makeCar` does not have the instances' prototype on its `.prototype` property. The `instanceof` expression is equivalent to `Car.makeCar.prototype.isPrototypeOf(bmw)`. To make it work, you'd need to set

```
Car.makeCar.prototype = Car.prototype;
```

but that's weird. Just keep the standard patterns. If you want to declare your methods in a structural unit together with the constructor, wrap everything in an IEFE [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28256166/1048572) or just use an ES6 class

Comment: Whoa, insta-accept in exactly 7 seconds! That's hard to beat :-)