# Javascript constructor prototype usage

Tags: javascript

When creating an object (prior to ES6) one could instantiate an object like so...

```
var Animal = function(){}
```

and then

```
var dog = new Animal();
```

...

Inside the animal "class" one can add...

```
var Animal = function( name ){

   this.constructor.prototype.name = name;

}
```

The question is basically, **what is the difference** between using the regular `this` in oppose to using `this.constructor.prototype`

```
var Animal = function( name ){

   // what is the difference between this
   this.constructor.prototype.name = name;

   // and that
   this.name = name;

}
```

I know this kind of basic, if anyone would care to explain. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `this.name = name;` assigns value to field of instance. `this.constructor.prototype.name = name;` assigns value to ALL instances' fields `name`

Comment: `this.constructor.prototype` fields are JavaScript's prototypal OOP's equivalent of static fields.

Comment: It's _very_ unlikely that you'd ever want to use the first scenario.

Comment: One simply [does not assign to the prototype inside the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255957/assigning-prototype-methods-inside-the-constructor-function-why-not). And definitely not with dynamic values.

Comment: @Aaron They're not `static` at all. "shared instance properties" would be a proper description.

Comment: @Bergi Looks like the word has multiple meanings. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable#Object-oriented_programming) is what I meant (rather than the meaning above the linked §)

Comment: Instead of the second i would rather do `Animal.prototype.name = name`

Comment: @MysterX this small comment made a lot of sense after long time of being ignorant thinking this only affects the console.log output (variables are not shown in the top level only) ;P ... thanks, if you would put that in an answer I would give this a right answer.. maybe some other folks could enjoy `this`

Comment: @James after reading @MysterXs comment if I understand correctly `this.constructor.prototype` allows you to declare 'shared' variables, I could think of a few situations where this might be handy... something in the vicinity of `dog.applySomethingToAllAnimals()` - pardon the length

Comment: @levi that one line of code breaks so many principles of OOD I wouldn't know where to start.