# Bind child class 'this' to all parent prototype functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `Shape` class and a `Circle` class that inherits from the Shape class.

Shape.js

```
function Shape(id, name, color) {

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.color = color;

    Shape.prototype.getDisplayName = () => {
        return this.id + ":" + this.name;
    }
};

module.exports = Shape;
```

Circle.js

```
const Shape = require('./shape');

Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Circle.prototype.constructor = Circle;

function Circle(id, name, color, radius) {
    Shape.call(this, id, name, color);

    this.radius = radius;
};

module.exports = Circle;
```

This works fine, but when I have more than one Circle object, the `getDisplayName` function is using the wrong context.

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    let circle1 = new Circle('id1', 'Circle', 'red', 5);
    let circle2 = new Circle('id3', 'Circle', 'blue', 12);

    let shapes = [circle1, circle2];

    for(let shape in shapes){
        console.log(shapes[shape].getDisplayName());
    }

});
```

This prints out

```
id3:Circle
id3:Circle
```

I found a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) that gave a bit of help. By adding `this.getDisplayName = this.getDisplayName.bind(this)` to the Circle constructor, it works. However, I'd prefer not having to do this for every parent method on every child. Is there a better way?

Comment: [Never assign `.prototype` methods inside the constructor!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255957/assigning-prototype-methods-inside-the-constructor-function-why-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign to the prototype inside the constructor like that with an arrow function. All the instances will share the same prototype. You are creating a new arrow function on each call of the constructor where `this` is bound to the current instant. The result is `this` is set tot the last instance created for all instances.

You need to use a traditional function to allow `this` to bind to the correct object when the function is called.

Also, there's no reason to put it in the constructor. You only need to create this function once, not every time the constructor is called.

```js
"use strict";

function Shape(id, name, color) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.color = color;
};

Shape.prototype.getDisplayName = function() {
  return this.id + ":" + this.name;
}

Circle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Circle.prototype.constructor = Circle;

function Circle(id, name, color, radius) {
  Shape.call(this, id, name, color);
  this.radius = radius;
};

let circle1 = new Circle('id1', 'Circle', 'red', 5);
let circle2 = new Circle('id3', 'Circle', 'blue', 12);

let shapes = [circle1, circle2];

for (let shape in shapes) {
  console.log(shapes[shape].getDisplayName());
}
```