# Defining the custom-element's lifecycle callbacks inside of the constructor

Tags: javascript, callback, prototype, lifecycle, custom-element

The following defines, creates and finally inserts an instance of my *"autonomous custom element"* onto the container:

```js
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  static get elementName() {
    return 'my-custom-element';
  }

  constructor() {
    const self = super();
    let _myPrivateData = 'privateValue';

    // the following does not cause the callback to be invoked at all!
    MyCustomElement.prototype.connectedCallback = function() {
      console.log('connected!');
    };

    return self;
  }

  //// this would've got invoked anyways, but there's no access to the `_myPrivateData`
  // connectedCallback() {
  //     console.log('connected!');
  // }
}

let myCustomElementName = MyCustomElement.elementName;
customElements.define(myCustomElementName, MyCustomElement);

let myCustomElement = document.createElement(myCustomElementName);
let container = document.getElementById('container');
container.appendChild(myCustomElement);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

I've defined the [`connectedCallback`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks) inside of the "constructor" to have access to `_myPrivateData`, but then the callback does not get invoked at all! Having the identical code-excerpt immediately after the "class body" does cause the callback to be invoked in expense of not having access to `_myPrivateData`.

Why is that? How shall I approach the issue to have access to `_myPrivateData` (preserving its *"private"* nature) and have the callback invocation working?

Comment: Apart from the custom-element-specific answer below, [you should never define prototype methods inside the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28255957/assigning-prototype-methods-inside-the-constructor-function-why-not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the Custom Element implementation you must define all the callbacks before the elemennt is defined with `customElements.define()`. These callbacks are readonly.

To deal with private values, you could define you own custom callback that would be invoked by the standard `connectedCallback()` method.

See the example below:

```js
class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    let _myPrivateData = 'privateValue'

    // the following does not cause the callback to be invoked at all!
    this.connectedCallback = function() {
      console.log('connected! : ' + _myPrivateData )
    }
  }

  connectedCallback() {
      this.connectedCallback()
  }
}

customElements.define('my-custom-element', MyCustomElement)
```

```html
<my-custom-element></my-custom-element>
```

**Update**

Effective lifecycle callbacks are actually *readonly / frozen*. You cannot modify them once the custom element is defined.

Consider that, when you call `customElements.define()`, the lifecycles callbacks are copied to the Custom Element Registry, from the `class` callback entries with the same name, or set to `void()` if the callback name doesn't exist.

When an instance of the custom element is created, these are the callback copies that are called, not the callback class `prototype` methods. You cannot access and therefore modify these copies.

You can still modifiy the class callbacks (the `prototype` entries) but it won't affect the custom element lifecyle.

The will enforce the consistancy of the life cycle for all the same custom element instances.

Comment: A super sharp answer! Thank you! But why the `MyCustomElement.prototype.connectedCallback = ...` (inside of the constructor in the original post) doesn't cause the callback to be invoked at all, while having the identical code-excerpt immediately after the "class body" (just before the `customElements.define()`) does cause the callback to be invoked?

Comment: @goodUser thanks. see the update, I hope it'sa little  clearer

Comment: I do appreciate your responses, I got their "readonly" nature, but the _"class methods"_ (you've denoted as being "`class` callback entries") are essentially "prototype" methods (it's just a [shorter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Prototype_methods)). The same prototype notation "works" when you put it just after the class body (before the `customElements.define()`), while it's doesn't work inside of the constructor, [why is that?](https://jsfiddle.net/dyopbn7t/)

Comment: because inisde the constructor the custom element was already defined, so it's too late to define the callbacks (they have been already copied/frozen)

Comment: You've nailed it! I truly appreciate your super-sharp efforts! Thank you.